# Locating a specific record in an aggregation of a Mongo DB collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on a reporting project that deal with monthly orders
We have orders coming into MongoDB in the below format

```
order:{
 _id: 123456789012123456789012,
 items:[
    {code:'ITEM1', qty:5},{code:'ITEM2', qty:6}
 ]
}
```

My requirement is to find out how a specific item ranks against other items in over all performance

I wrote this aggregation to first find out the grouping of each item and the number of quantities ordered

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  [
    { $unwind : "$items" },
    { $group : {code : "$code" , tot_ord: { $sum : "$qty" } } },
    { $sort : { tot_ord : -1 } }
  ]
)
```

So this should give me a sorted list of items with highest orders first.

But how would I get the rank of a specific item without looping? I am talking about almost 500,000 different items so I want to avoid looping

Thanks for the help in advance.

UPDATE:
THIS is what I finally had it working. This example is using Node.js. I am posting this so that it is useful for somebody in future

```
function aggregate(mongoDb,collection_item, pipeline, next){    
    mongoDb.collection(collection_item, function(err, collection) {
        collection.aggregate(pipeline,function(err,result) {            
            if(err){
                console.log('Error aggregating: ' + err);
                next({'error':'An error has occurred - ' + err});
            }else{
                next(result);    
            }            
        });        
    });
}

function calculateOrderRank(itemId){

    aggregate(mongoDb, "orders", 
            [
              { $unwind : "$items" },
              { $match : { items.code : itemId} },              
              { $group : { _id : "$items.code" , tot_qty: { $sum : "$items.qty" } } }

            ],function(result) {
                var itemQty = result[0].tot_qty;
                data.aggregate(mongoDb, "orders", 
                [
                  { $unwind : "$items" },
                  { $group : { _id : "$items.code" , tot_qty: { $sum : "$items.qty" } } },
                  { $match: {tot_qty:{$gt:itemQty}} },
                  { $group : {_id:null, rank : { $sum : 1 } } },
                ],function(result) {
                    var rank = 1;
                    if (result && result.length>0) {
                        rank = result[0].rank + 1;
                    }
                    res.send({item_id:itemId, rank:rank, score:itemQty});
                });
            }
    );

}
```

Comment: that's not a legal aggregation pipeline - your "$group" is not structured correctly.

Comment: this feature does not exist in aggregation framework at this time anyway.  You would need https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065 to be implemented to be able to get the rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not exist in aggregation framework at this time. You would need [jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065) to be implemented to be able to get the rankings.

Meanwhile you can do this with two aggregation framework queries.

The first one would aggregate and get the totals for the specific item in question (it would be similar to what you include in your question, but your $group format is incorrect, it should be `{$group: {_id:"$items.code", <etc>}`).  You would start with limiting "items.code" to a particular value.

The second one would be for all the collection and then after aggregation you could do `{match:{count:{$gt:<count-for-that-one-item>}}` and then do another `$group` to count how many "totals" were higher than this one item's.  That gives you the item's rank.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I will test this and will update.

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I am also posting the working code in the update